# Magento 2.4 Favicon won't show up in Google search result. Is there way to hide static content version number for specific content?

Tags: magento2.4, favicons

Favicon of my site working correctly within my site.
but externally, when I see my site in google search result, Favicon has not been registered.

when I check link tag of favicon in head section of html,
url path of href includes static content version number.

```
link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://example.com/static/versionxxxxxxx/frontend.../favicon.ico"
```

this version number change each time when static content deploy executed.

I am guessing the constant change of href prevent registering favicon in google.

I know Magento can show off the version number by the configuration.
But whole static contents version will turn off, I do not like to turn off this feature.

Does someone have good advice to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the below query in your **magento database.**

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

Then run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Your **version number** will be removed from the static urls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I know above solution.  I would like to keep alive the versioning feature.  Is there a way to remove version number only for favicon href?